# Android - Load image from drawable to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager include three pages. Each page, it has a ImageViews, and I will load images from drawable set to it later.

This is my code:

On Fragment:

```
@BindView(R.id.viewPager)    
ViewPager mViewPager;

...

private List<Integer> getIntroResourceIds() {
    List<Integer> introResourceIds = new ArrayList<>();
    introResourceIds.add(R.layout.layout_intro_step1);
    introResourceIds.add(R.layout.layout_intro_step2);
    introResourceIds.add(R.layout.layout_intro_step3);
    return introResourceIds;
}
```

On each layout intro, I have a `ImageView` with the different id. Such as in `layout_intro_step_1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/quickpay_intro_step3_image"
            style="@style/IntroImage" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, I can't set the images view for each layout intro when user click next page. Please help me this problem.

Comment: You want to set image in the `Fragment` outside of your `Fragment`?

Comment: Yes, @ReazMurshed

Comment: You cannot actually do that. The best you can do is while creating the `Fragment` you can `setArguments` and then `getArguments` inside your `Fragment` to get the image to be placed in your `ImageView`. Check how to pass data from an `Activity` to `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom pager adapter

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

 int[] mResources = {

        R.drawable.first,

        R.drawable.second,

        R.drawable.third,

        R.drawable.fourth,

        R.drawable.fifth,

        R.drawable.sixth

};


    Context mContext;

    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

 

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {

        mContext = context;

        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

 

    @Override

    public int getCount() {

        return mResources.length;

    }

 

    @Override

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);

    }

 

    @Override

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

 

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

 

        container.addView(itemView);

 

        return itemView;

    }

    @Override

    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }

}
```

In your Activity setup view pager adapter

```
mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```